# matchpairs makes vim slow

Tags: performance, delimiter-matching

I use `set matchpairs+=<:>` in my config (to help when editing HTML, for instance), but I just noticed it made vim very slow when editing emails.

Is there a way to have this setting without paying a performance penalty? (e.g., automatically disabling it in cases like emails when it's obviously not relevant to see the numerous `>` as delimiters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The slowness of delimiter matching is not caused by vim itself but by the [matchparen plugin](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim), which is part of the vim distribution and loaded by default in `/etc/vim/vimrc` in Debian. (This is why I still had the problem without a vimrc.)

Fortunately the matchparen plugin supports a timeout when looking for matches, so the slowness can be avoided by setting those timeout to lower values. I added the following to my vimrc:

```
let g:matchparen_timeout = 2
let g:matchparen_insert_timeout = 2
```

2 milliseconds is plenty of time on modern machines to find a relevant delimiter, and when scrolling down in [this file](http://paste.fulltxt.net/7BxA) on my machine, display is no longer slugging and CPU usage for vim stays at 15% or so.

**Edit:** actually I increased it to 20, otherwise I sometimes see it fail. This means there is still some sluggishness, but it's better than without the setting.

Answer (score 6):

If your emails have a particular file type, you could use `BufRead` or `BufNewFile` or `FileType` to turn off some matchpairs automatically:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.email set mps-=<:>
```

Comment: OK, but that's just a workaround, it means vim may also be slow on other file types, or on emails that aren't correctly detected. I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a generic way to fix this? Thanks, in any case!

Comment: I would suggest exactly the opposite: only set mps when editing HTML instead of making it the default.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it has something to do with your `.vimrc` somewhere else, I can still edit emails as long as 10000 lines without having any slowdown with

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

Can you try with an empty vimrc and start finding out by commenting out other things ?

Comment: The problem also occurs with just that setting. Using the trivial .vimrc http://paste.fulltxt.net/sov8ji, when I try opening http://paste.fulltxt.net/urbFS7i and scroll down by holding 'j', it gets sluggish essentially immediately. (Can you reproduce this? I have "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4", "2:7.4.826-1" from Debian amd64.) So I still claim this isn't any interaction with my other settings.

Comment: By the way, the problem is not specific to `<` and `>`, just opening with http://paste.fulltxt.net/7BxA with `syntax on` and trying to scroll should be enough to bring vim to its knees. I would be puzzled if there's nothing that can be done for that...